# How to query user skills in apex

Tags: apex, soql

What is the way to query skills and endorsements through soql / apex? Or export?

[image]

Any queries from Skill / SkillUser and others from developer console don't work, for instance, `Select SkillId From SkillUser`.

Comment: Looks like the right query could be `SELECT ProfileSkillId, UserId FROM ProfileSkillUser` if you look on this [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_profileskilluser.htm).

Comment: @MartinLezer it worked! I confused `SkillUser` and `Skill` objects with `ProfileSkill`. Do you know the difference?

Comment: Glad I could help. No sorry I don't know these objects.

Comment: @MartinLezer Looks like you should convert your comment to an answer.

Comment: @KeithC You're right!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the right query could be `SELECT ProfileSkillId, UserId FROM ProfileSkillUser` if you look on this [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_profileskilluser.htm).